# Completeness relation for non-hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Basic question. Suppose you have a complex matrix $A$ with different (non-zero) eigenvalues associated with their corresponding eigenvectors. Does it exist a completeness relation for these matrices? For hermitian matrices, I think this is always true and the relation is

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{dim} |\Psi\rangle_n (|\Psi\rangle_n )^T = I,
$$

where $T$ denotes the transpose and $I$ the identity operator. My concern is that in general for $A$ one would have left and right eigenvectors, but consider for simplicity that the left eigenvector $|\Psi\rangle_L$ fulfills:

$$
|\Psi\rangle_L = (|\Psi\rangle_R^*)^T
$$

where the asterisk denotes complex conjugation.

Comment: user2820579!
I am also interested in this kind of question (studying non-hermitian problems in quantum mechanics); I solved one problem for the case of degeneracy and there is a thing called "generalized eigenvectors", which you use to construct the Jordan normal form [Chappers provided the link to wiki], but do these vectors along with normal eigenvectors (in regular sense) create a complete basis or mb it is overcomplete? I do not remember any theorem on that from undergrad linear algebra course, mb I have forgotten something.
Have you found the answer?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know the answer, but for the down answer I would say no in the general sense. Still, I think it is highly possible to construct a complete basis when the matrix has a special structure (for example scattering matrices, or transport-related Green's functions). We have to dig in the journals or ask somebody who works with these things.

Answer (score 0):

No; the usual example is
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, $$
which has only one eigenvector: $(1,0)$.

Comment: Well I'm not asking for cases where you have a zero as an eigenvalue. Corrected the body of the question.

Comment: The answer's still no: take
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
for example, with single eigenvector $(1,1)$.

Comment: But I said non-degenerate eigenvalues.

Comment: Not in those words.

Comment: No, it says different (non-zero) eigenvalues.

Comment: In which case, the answer is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form .